# boost::multi_array containing square boost::ublas::matrix<double> of different sizes

Tags: c++, boost

I was wondering why this works and if it's really risky or not...

I want the elements of a boost::multi_array to hold boost::ublas matrices of different sizes (sizes defined at runtime).

In the header I've defined `typedef::boost::ublas::matrix<double> Matrix;` and `typedef::boost::multi_array<Matrix,1> Tensor;`.

Now in `main(){}` I've made a `Tensor tensor(boost::extents[some_number]);` and then "allocated memory" to it by doing:

```
for(int i=0; i<some_number; i++){
    tensor[i] = Matrix(runtime_defined_number, runtime_defined_number);
}
```

Now I pass `Tensor &tensor` around to my functions and do stuff with it...

Is this crazy? If so, why does it work? Is there a better way of doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can create a vector of matrices since you work only with one-dimentional array. There is no need in boost::multi_array here.